# nav not change color on scroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem. I tried to do so that when I go down the navbar changes color it worked but the problem is that when I go up to the level of the slider it stays in the color that it changed. In this link you will find the whole code https://jsfiddle.net/khdtc6bn/ this is my js code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 300) {
          $(".navbar-custom").css("background" , "blue");
        }
    })
  })
```

I would like that when I am all up it takes back this basic color, where is the problem in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the color again if the scroll is less or equal 300:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
        if (scroll > 300) {
          $(".navbar-custom").css("background" , "blue");
        }
        else{
          $(".navbar-custom").css("background" , "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37)");
        }
    })
  })
```

Comment: I suggest resetting it to `""` instead. this will remove the inline style and fall back to the value authored via css: `$(".navbar-custom").css("background" , "");`

Comment: @whitespace just 1 question do you know how can i do for when scroll color of font change too?

Comment: using css("color",...)

Comment: @mgm793     if (scroll > 300) {
        $(".navbar-custom").css("background" , "white"),
        $(".navbar-custom").css("color" , "green");
      } i have try like this doesn-t work how need to do?

Comment: You need to use a semicolon `;` at the end of each statement, not a comma `,`: `if (scroll > 300) { $(".navbar-custom").css("background" , "white"); $(".navbar-custom").css("color" , "green"); }`

Comment: You can however combine those two operation in one call: `if (scroll > 300) { $(".navbar-custom").css({ background: "white", color: "green" }); } ` (https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-properties)

Comment: As an alternative, you can add/remove a class via javascript and style that class via css: `if (scroll > 300) { $(".navbar-custom").addClass('sticky'); } else { $(".navbar-custom").removeClass('sticky'); } ` (https://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/class-attribute/) and CSS: `.sticky { background-color: "white"; color: "green"; }`